# Erro em site após troca de servidor

Tags: php

A página carrega esse erro abaixo:

> Message: Non-static method util::loadView() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Código onde a mensagem indica o erro:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        util::loadView('home/index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que parece você deseja carregar uma `view`. O certo deveria ser utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('home/index');
    }
}
```

Comment: A principio funcionou, Obrigado.

Comment: De nada, fico feliz de ter ajudado.